# html - php - database phpmyadmin - graph/charts

Tags: php, html, graph, charts, phpmyadmin

Can anyone help me? Is there any ways to make charts using data stored in my database? linked them and produce charts i my dashboard?

please enlighten me on how to do it.

*code has nothing to do with question*

```
        echo"</br>";
        echo "<b><u>Total Profit earned </u></b>" ;
        echo"</br>";
        $query1 = "SELECT country, SUM(profit) FROM `table 1` GROUP BY country"; 
        $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
            echo "". $row['country']. " = RM ". $row['SUM(profit)'];
            echo "<br />";
        }

echo"</td>";
echo"<td width='60%'>";
    echo "</br>";
    echo "<table border=2 align=center> ";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td colspan=15 align='middle'><h3> Historical Data from Quarter 1 2012 until Quarter 3 2014</h3></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align='middle'><b>No</b></td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'><b>Retailer Country</b></td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'><b>Method Type</b></td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'><b>Type</b></td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'><b>Product Line</b></td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'><b>Product Type</b></td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'><b>Year</b></td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'><b>Quarter</b></td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'><b>Revenue</b></td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'><b>Quantity</b></td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'><b>Gross Margin</b></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $series = 1;
        while($HData=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $Country=$HData['Country'];
            $Method=$HData['Method'];
            $Type=$HData['Type'];
            $PLine=$HData['PLine'];
            $PType=$HData['PType'];
            $Year=$HData['Year'];
            $Quarter=$HData['Quarter'];
            $Revenue=$HData['Revenue'];
            $Quantity=$HData['Quantity'];
            $GMargin=$HData['GMargin'];

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td align='middle'>$series</td>";
                echo "<td align='middle'>$Country</td>";
                echo "<td align='middle'>$Method</td>";
                echo "<td align='middle'>$Type</td>";
                echo "<td align='middle'>$PLine</td>";
                echo "<td align='middle'>$PType</td>";
                echo "<td align='middle'>$Year</td>";
                echo "<td align='middle'>$Quarter</td>";
                echo "<td align='middle'>$Revenue</td>";
                echo "<td align='middle'>$Quantity</td>";
                echo "<td align='middle'>$GMargin   </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        $series++; 
        }
```

echo"";

Comment: if data is available for frontend through PHP, you can do it by using HTML5 canvas

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using HTML5 Canvas with the data available from PHP...Codepen URL for reference
http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/Meayrb

```
       var vertical = {
        a: 1084,
        b: 92,
        c: 84,
        d :49

      };
```

I have used above mentioned sample data to create pie and bar chart..you use your dataset and create charts from there..... and those charts gets scaled automatically to values...Hope this helpful for you

Comment: but how to extract data from database? can i directly extract data or i have to do it manually? thankyouu

Comment: Yes.. You can extract data from database by php and data can be used by JavaScript to build charts..reference link for extracting data by php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331353/retrieve-data-from-db-and-display-it-in-table-in-php-see-this-code-whats-wron