# Submit form and read it on different page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form on my website and need to save the submitted data, the submission date and time in a html file to show the data on a different page.

```
<form>
  <label>Name</label>      <input type="text" />
  <label>Email</label>      <input type="email" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The form looks something like this. After pressing Submit, the data should be written in the file submissions.html, above the existing content, to show the most recent submissions on top.

```
*** 02 ***
Submited: 2016/12/06 04:32
Tony DiNozzo 
TonyDiNozzo@gmail.com

*** 01 ***
Submited: 2016/12/05 16:08
Timothy McGee
TimothyMcGee@gmail.com
```

What would be the most elegant way to accomplish that in php or javascript?

Comment: First of all, u have to name your inputs like this: 
`<input name="name" type="text" />`

What exacly you want to achieve? Just display last submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is very simple. you have to create a file called <kbd>file.php</kbd> in that file you place following code:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_GET["name"]) && isset($_GET["email"]) && !empty($_GET["name"]) && !empty($_GET["email"])) {

    if(isset($_SESSION['view']))
    {
        $_SESSION['view']=$_SESSION['view']+1;
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['view']=1;
    }

    $myfile = fopen("submissions.html", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");

    $line = "*** ". $_SESSION["view"] . " ***";
    $date = "Submitted: " . date("Y/m/d H:i", time());
    $name = $_GET["name"];
    $email = $_GET["email"];
    $line2 = "";

    fwrite($myfile, "\n". $line);
    fwrite($myfile, "\n". $date);
    fwrite($myfile, "\n". $name);
    fwrite($myfile, "\n". $email);
    fwrite($myfile, "\n". $line2);

    fclose($myfile);
} else {
    header('Location: index.html');
}

?>
```

and in the <kbd>index.html</kbd> this content:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="file.php">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input title="name" required name="name" type="text" />
        <label>Email</label>
        <input title="email" required name="email" type="email" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### for explanaition:

this code will count for the current session. its required for `*** (int)+1 ***`

```
if(isset($_SESSION['view']))
{
    $_SESSION['view']=$_SESSION['view']+1;
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['view']=1;
}
```

here you open the file. `a` stands for `append`:

```
$myfile = fopen("submissions.html", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

this code will format your output:

```
$line = "*** ". $_SESSION["view"] . " ***";
$date = "Submitted: " . date("Y/m/d H:i", time());
$name = $_GET["name"];
$email = $_GET["email"];
$line2 = "";
```

and will look like:
[image]

then we write every line:

```
fwrite($myfile, "\n". $line);
fwrite($myfile, "\n". $date);
fwrite($myfile, "\n". $name);
fwrite($myfile, "\n". $email);
fwrite($myfile, "\n". $line2);

fclose($myfile);
```

Comment: I like your idea and the explanation helps a lot. However, the script prints 'Unable to open file!'. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Gabriel Winkler Did you chmod the file with 777 or 764 ? Is your folder writable? Does the file submissions.html exist?

Comment: Got it. Permissions were the problem. The code works really nicely. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think use php...

```
<form method="post" action="submissions.php">
<label>Name</label><input type="text" name="name"/>
<label>Email</label><input type="email" name="email"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

in submissions.php

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$creadate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
if(isset($_POST['submit']{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

   echo "Submitted ". $creadate;
   echo $name;
   echo $email;
}
```

CMIIW, I'm newbie :3

Comment: OP asks for save and read back reverse order, your answer does not contain that, and what if `$_POST['submit']` is empty why are you echo-ing the date

Comment: put the echo values in the if condition

Comment: ooppss...I'm sorry, forgot about that. thanks for your correction

Answer (score 0):

first add method `post` and `action` of where you want to submit the data

```
    <form method="post" action="yourpage.php">
      <label>Name</label><input type="text"  name="text"/>
      <label>Email</label><input type="email name="email"" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

to get the data.
put the POST

`$_POST[`name of input`]` when you click the submit button you will be redirected to the other page and the data will be posted in the next page to see it it works try echoing it using `echo $_POST[`name of input`]`

Comment: data need to be save in table then retrieve latest data from the database and display it in tabular form or the way want to display.see for the explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331353/retrieve-data-from-db-and-display-it-in-table-in-php-see-this-code-whats-wron